# Como atualizar um documento dentro de outro documento sem deletar os dados anteriores no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Na verdade são 2 dúvidas que tenho:
Imagine uma coleção `livro` com estrutura:

```
{
    "Título" : "MongoDB para iniciantes",
    "Tags" : [ 
        "MongoDB", 
        "NoSQL"
    ],
    "Comentários" : [ 
        {
           "Comentarista" : "Ana",
           "Comentário" : "Muito bom"
        }, 
        {
           "Comentarista" : "Zé",
           "Comentário" : "Gostei demais"
        }
    ]
}
```

**DÚVIDAS:**

1. Como faço pra acrescentar uma nova Tag, sem sobrescrever as que já existem?
2. Como faço para inserir um novo comentário sem sobrescrever os comentários já existentes?

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar elementos em um array no MongoDB, você pode utilizar o operador `$push`

> **$push**
>
> The $push operator appends a specified value to an array.

[Referência](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push)

Você irá passar o `id` de seu `document` e o operador `$push`, segundo do nome e o valor que deseja incluir. Para incluir uma tag em seu document você utilizará o seguinte comando:

```
db.getCollection('livro').update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $push: { "Tags": "SqlServer" } }
)
```

Agora, para incluir um novo comentário em seu document, você fará exatamente a query acima, com a diferença que você precisará passar um `object`:

```
{ $push: { "Comentários" : { "Comentarista" : "Leonardo", "Comentário" : "Demais" } } }
```

Também existe o operador [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#addtoset), que só irá incluir um valor se o mesmo não estiver presente no array.